# Display image in GridView using Picasso

Tags: java, android, gridview, picasso

I want to build an app that displays images in a gridview by using the picasso library. This is my code. The image didn't load. In Picasso log, after request it always error to load. Can you help me ?Please Thank you

**UPDATE**

CustomGridViewAdapter.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Nicky-PC on 4/9/2016.
 */
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<gridItem> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<gridItem> data = new ArrayList<gridItem>();

    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                                 ArrayList<gridItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setGridData(ArrayList<gridItem> mGridData)
    {
        this.data=mGridData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        gridItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getBarang());
        Picasso.with(context).
                load(item.getImageUrl()).
                into(holder.imageItem);
        return row;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    JSONParser jParser= new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameList;
    JSONArray names=null;
    GridView data;
    private static final String URL_TEST_BARANG= "http://lomapod.azurewebsites.net/readBarang.php";
    private static final String TAG_PESAN = "message";
    private static final String TAG_HASIL = "result";
    private static final String TAG_BARANG = "nama_barang";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE= "image_name";
    ImageView imageview;
    CustomGridViewAdapter mGridAdapter;
    ArrayList<gridItem> mGridData;
    public  MainActivity()
    {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        data=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.lvSeller);
        nameList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        imageview =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mGridData=new ArrayList<>();
        mGridAdapter=new CustomGridViewAdapter(this,R.layout.grid_item,mGridData);


        new AmbilDataJson("1").execute();
    }


    public class AmbilDataJson extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        String id;
        int sukses=0;

        public AmbilDataJson(String id) {
            this.id=id;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_penjual",id));
            try
            {

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_TEST_BARANG, "GET", params);
                gridItem item=null;
                if(json != null)
                {
                    sukses = json.getInt(TAG_PESAN);
                    if(sukses == 0)
                    {
                        nameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                        Log.d("Semua Nama: ", json.toString());
                        names = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HASIL);

                        for(int i = 0; i < names.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject c = names.getJSONObject(i);
                            String barang = c.getString(TAG_BARANG);
                            String image = "lomapod.esy.es/assets/"+c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                            item = new gridItem();
                            item.setBarang(barang);
                            item.setImageUrl(image);

                            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

                            map.put(TAG_BARANG,barang);
                            map.put(TAG_IMAGE,image);
                            nameList.add(map);
                            mGridData.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if(sukses == 0)
            {
                CustomGridViewAdapter adapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,R.layout.grid_item,mGridData);
                if(mGridData.size()>0)
                {
                    mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
                    data.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error - No Data      Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CustomGridViewAdapter adapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this,R.layout.grid_item,mGridData);
            mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
            data.setAdapter(adapter);
```

mGridData is empty, you have not added data for this list. And you don't not need initialize new adapter.

Comment: how to initialize mGridData? can u tell me how? i get confused with it

Comment: i had initialize it, but it just display the name, image hasn't appear, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add values to mGridData thats why its not showing anything. Before passing values to adapter check the size of mGridData.

```
    `@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(sukses == 0)
        {
            CustomGridViewAdapter adapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this,R.layout.grid_item,mGridData);
           if(mGridData.size()>0)
              {
            mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
            data.setAdapter(adapter);
             }
          else 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error - No Data      Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }`
```

Comment: i had initialize it, but it just display the name, image hasn't appear, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `GridView` is not showing anything is because the `ArrayList<gridItem>` you are passing to your `CustomGridViewAdapter` is **empty**.

You have initialized your `ArrayList<gridItem>` in `MainActivity` but *never added a any item to the list.*

There are some things you need to change in your program to make it work.
Since you are added server response in the `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameList`, you need to pass that `ArrayList` to your `Adapter`, and then use that ArrayList's items to bind in your grid's `textView` and `imageView`.

In `onPostExecute()`, initialize your adapter as,

```
CustomGridViewAdapter adapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.grid_item, nameList);
data.setAdapter(adapter);    
//you don't even need to call mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData) method.
```

Also change your Adapter's constructor as,

```
public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameList) { 
    ....
}
```

Comment: i had initialize it, but it just display the name, image hasn't appear, can you help me?